# execSQL: is bindargs better?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I was wondering in the execSQL method which can take 1 or 2 arguments.
Why using the second method, if I can use an object to directly do my operation on an SQLite db?

In example:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TableName +" VALUES (null, ?)",
        new Object[] { type.getName() })
```

is this better than using this

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TableName +" VALUES (null,"+  type.getName() +")")
```

is the 1st example more secure?
faster when executing?
easier to read...
or is it the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method **1** is better.

It saves you from SQL injection, for instance.
Because it handles the datatypes for you.

Meaning that it converts the strings when needed by adding the string delimiters and converting the apostrophes.

I.e.:

To work correctly, you should write method **2** like

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TableName + " VALUES (null, '" +  type.getName().replace("'", "''") + "')");
```

So...

`is the 1st example more secure?` Yes.
`faster when executing?` Not sure if it is.
`easier to read` Yes, once you get used to it (primarily opinion based).
`... or is it the same?` No, for what discussed above.