# How to prevent sql injection in loop through VALUES

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert an `ArrayList` of `String`s to a table in an sqlite database.

I've written a loop that adds `String`s from an `ArrayList` to an sqlite database query using `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper`.

The query is vulnerable for sql injection and is not optimal. I've found these links
[using PreparedStatement](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement), [using SQLiteStatement](http://ziniestro.com/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-android/). I haven't found examples of preventing sql injection in a loop like this. For demonstration's sake, I've put the initialization of the `ArrayList` in the example.

```
ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<>();

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String addBulkQuery = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_DESCRIPTIONS + "(" + KEY_ID + ", " + KEY_DESCRIPTION + ") VALUES";
if (descriptions.size() > 0) {
    addBulkQuery += "(" + id + ", " + descriptions.get(0) + ")";
    for (int i = 1; i < descriptions.size(); i++) {
        addBulkQuery += ", (" + id + ", " + descriptions.get(i) + ")";
    }
}
```

What would be the most secure solution to add an `ArrayList` of `String`s or `Object`s to the sqlite database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34619804/5018798

Comment: @GavinHarris I understand how it would work if I was inserting a single row. That's what the two hyperlinks in my post and the hyperlink in your post explain. I would prefer not to do a seperate insert statement for each row i'm inserting. I would prefer to put all the rows I want to insert within the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Does that answer help? You in effect make anything that a user can enter a bind parameter. You can structure your SQL to accept `n` number of parameters, you just need to track the number of parameters and pass in the correct number on execSQL

Answer (score 1):

Try using a SQLiteStatement, something like the below:

```
ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> bindArgs = new ArrayList<>(descriptions.size() * 2);

String values = "";
if (descriptions.size() > 0) {

    values += "(?,?)";
    bindArgs.add(id);
    bindArgs.add(descriptions.get(0));

    for (int i = 1; i < descriptions.size(); i++) {
        values += ",(?,?)";
        bindArgs.add(id);
        bindArgs.add(descriptions.get(i));
    }
}

String addBulkQuery =  String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s, %s) VALUES %s", TABLE_DESCRIPTIONS, KEY_ID, KEY_DESCRIPTION, values);

SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(addBulkQuery);

statement.bindAllArgsAsStrings( bindArgs.toArray(new String[0]) );

statement.executeInsert();
```

I have assumed the `id` is a String and therefore I can use the `statement.bindAllArgsAsStrings` method to bind the variables to the statement. *(Sorry I also rewrote your Strings to use String.format, I find it easier to read, you can ignore if you like)*

OLD Answer:

Look at using Bind Variables. Rewrite your SQL so that anywhere you accept user input, enter in a "?" and then use `db.execSQL(sqlString, Arguments);`

So you want the SQL to look like (before you execute):

```
INSERT INTO <tableName> (<key_id>, <key_description>)
VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), ...
```

You will then need to flatten your ArrayList into an Object Array interspersed with whatever `id` is!

Comment: According to the documentation for `execSQL` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])) you can/t/shouldn't perform INSERT queries with `execSQL()`. Are you referring to `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()` or some other API?

Comment: You are right and I answered too quickly. I will edit the answer in the AM.